# Mobile number validator in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a textbox that use `RegularExpressionValidator` by this ValidationExpression :

```
(0|\+98)?([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}9[0-4]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}){8}
```

So this isn't useful for `09012223344`

Please help me!

Comment: `^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{11}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is ValidationExpression for 09(01234)xxxxxxxx mobile Number

(0|+98)?([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}9[0|1|2|3|4]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}){8}

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try on a more generic regex like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexpName" runat="server"     
                                    ErrorMessage="This expression does not validate." 
                                    ControlToValidate="txtName"     
                                    ValidationExpression="^[\+0-9\-\(\)]{8,12}$" />
```